# how to use array from axios post in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm fairly new to React Native. I have successfully fetched the required array through axios.post, in the following format:

```
"hospitals": [
        {
            "title": "Holy Family Hospital Rawalpindi",
            "distance": "71.45372179866516"
        },
        {
            "title": "Fauji Foundation Hospital Islamabad",
            "distance": "62.242918533343705"
        },
        {
            "title": "PIMS Hospital Islamabad",
            "distance": "80.0576175928936"
        }
```

I'm trying to display only the titles in a dropdown list and continuously failing. I just dont know the correct format/protocol for this (ie how to use individual values). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please tell us which dropdown you are using ?

Comment: Thanks for replying back. I'm using Searchable dropdown, but in addition to that, I actually wanna use these values (in conditional statements), and I dont know how to do that. I cannot access them via indexes or anything so what would be the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

https://reactnative.dev/docs/picker
I think u wanna use that.

just map the items. like that:

```
 <Picker
        selectedValue={selectedValue}
        style={{ height: 50, width: 150 }}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}
      >
   data.map((data)=>{
return(  <Picker.Item label=data.title value=data.title />)
  })
       
      </Picker>
```